# Question About Printing a Sequential Pattern

Tags: c, printf, sequence

I am trying to get an output like this for the given n variables. If n=5 the output should be as follows:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

In my code, when I print I get the output reversed and without spaces. I have tried many ways to achieve this but couldn't find a solution. The output I receive for n=5 is:

```
*********
*******
*****
***
*
```

The following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n=0;
    int b=0;

    puts("Please Enter an Integer");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(n;n>0;n--){
        b = 2*n - 1;
        for(b;b>0;b--){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many questions about printing pyramids on SO.  You should be able to find one or more that help. However, your required output needs leading blanks on at least some lines. You never print any blanks.  This means your output is never going to match what's wanted.  Working out how many blanks to print is 80% of the battle in the pyramid you're dealing with.  There are variants where you need to build up to longer lines and then down to shorter lines, or vice versa; the problems are different there. (Your loop counts down; you need it to count up. That'll turn the pyramid right way up.)

Comment: What is output if n is even?

Comment: The goal of your assignment is to teach you the use of nested loops. Apart from the lack of printing blanks (as JL mentioned above), playing with different ways of setting up two nested loops is all you need. Count up, count down, count to numbers calculated from the outer loop.... Play. Learn. Succeed. Copying from other questions on StackOverflow will give you only the "succeed" part,but believe me, the first two are more important.

Comment: Well put @Yunnosch.  I would recommend you start b trying to reverse the order printed, _then_ worry about spacing.

Comment: Reading through the answers for this question, and others you can find if you search should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529124/making-a-hash-pyramid

Comment: @Yunnosch and learn to use your debugger

Comment: @Yunnosch I am not trying to cheat my way through my assignments, I just couldn't find a solution after hardworking. After some more tinkering and advices in the comments I believe that I have found a solution. I admire your comment but I just wanted to tell that my intent is not to cheat.

Answer (score 0):

After some intense brainstorming I have managed to find the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int n=0;
    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    int c=0;

    puts("Please Enter an Integer");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(n;n>0;n--){          // Loop indicating that the pattern will run n times.

        c=n-1;               // Loop for the spaces to align the pattern to the centre.
        for(c;c>0;c--){      
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(a;a<b;a++){      // Loop for the pattern.
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
        b=b+2;
        a=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `print("%*s", n-1, " ");` instead of `Loop for the spaces to align the pattern to the centre.`.

Comment: You can use `for(b=1;n>0;n--, b += 2){;` at parent `for` instead of `b=b+2;` at the end of it.

Comment: You should use `for(int a=0;a<b;a++)` instead of declaring `a` in top of `main` and assigning to `0` in the bottom of the parent `for`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is more steady and comprised per contra to the previous.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,a,b;

    puts("Please Enter an Integer");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(b=1;n>0;n--, b += 2){
        if(n!=1) {
            printf("%*s", n - 1, " ");
        }else{break;}

        for(a=0;a<b;a++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```